# ASP.NET MVC URL decode

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, decode

I have an action like this:

```
<%=Html.ActionLink("My_link", "About", "Home", new RouteValueDictionary { 
    { "id", "Österreich" } }, null)%>
```

This produces the following link: http://localhost:1855/Home/About/%C3%96sterreich

I want a link which looks like this - localhost:1855/Home/About/Österreich

I have tried.

```
Server.HtmlDecode("Österreich")
HttpUtility.UrlDecode("Österreich")
```

Neither seems to be helping. What else can I try to get my desired result?

Comment: Do you get an error if you don't encode the parameter with the umlaut?

Comment: No error, the url works fine. Hits the correct action method and passes in the parameter. I just want the url to be "friendly".

Comment: No. using MVC 1.0. Are you using an actionlink the same way as me?

Comment: A side note: If you are targeting only German and not the more complex unicode languages (chinese, japanese, hebrew, arabic), you may consider "transliterating" (not sure if this word is correct for simple removal of diacritics on characters and ä->ae conversions) the characters into their unaccented versions. In german search results, Google takes the transformation into account when doing highlighting and additionaly your transliterated url will display correctly in all browsers. Example: http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&q=schoen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is an issue with your browser (IE).

Your code is correct as it is, no explicit UrlEncoding needed.

```
<%=Html.ActionLink("My_link", "About", "Home", new RouteValueDictionary { 
{ "id", "Österreich" } }, null)%>
```

There is nothing wrong with ASP.NET MVC. See unicode urls on the web, e.g. http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9B%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA in IE and in a browser that handles unicode in URLs correctly.

E.g. chrome displays unicode URLs without any problem. IE does not decode "special" unicode characters in address bar.

This is only a cosmetic issue.

Comment: Just verified this - FF displays them nicely, but the source shows the encoded URL.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be and IE issue. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

According to [RFC 1738 Uniform Resource Locators (URL)](http://www.freesoft.org/CIE/RFC/1738/index.htm), only US-ASCII is supported, all other characters must be encoded.

> ```
> 2.2. URL Character Encoding Issues
>
> URLs are sequences of characters, i.e., letters, digits, and special
> ```
>
> characters. A URLs may be represented
>   in a variety of ways: e.g., ink on
>   paper, or a sequence of octets in a
>   coded character set. The
>   interpretation of a URL depends only
>   on the identity of the characters
>   used.
>
> ```
> In most URL schemes, the sequences of characters in different parts of a
> ```
>
> URL are used to represent sequences of
>   octets used in Internet protocols. For
>   example, in the ftp scheme, the host
>   name, directory name and file names
>   are such sequences of octets,
>   represented by parts of the URL.
>   Within those parts, an octet may be
>   represented by the chararacter which
>   has that octet as its code within the
>   US-ASCII [20] coded character set.
>
> ```
> In addition, octets may be encoded by a character triplet consisting of
> ```
>
> the character "%" followed by the two
>   hexadecimal digits (from
>   "0123456789ABCDEF") which forming the
>   hexadecimal value of the octet. (The
>   characters "abcdef" may also be used
>   in hexadecimal encodings.)
>
> ```
> Octets must be encoded if they have no corresponding graphic
> ```
>
> character within the US-ASCII coded
>   character set, if the use of the
>   corresponding character is unsafe, or
>   if the corresponding character is
>   reserved for some other interpretation
>   within the particular URL scheme.
>
> ```
> No corresponding graphic US-ASCII:
>
> URLs are written only with the graphic printable characters of the
> ```
>
> US-ASCII coded character set. The
>   octets 80-FF hexadecimal are not used
>   in US-ASCII, and the octets 00-1F and
>   7F hexadecimal represent control
>   characters; these must be encoded.

Answer (score 1):

I think your desire for a non urlencode url is valid, but I don't think the tools actually make it easy to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Would putting the generated link inside an `<a>`, with the link text being the non-encoded string, not be good enough?  It would still look bad in the browser's URL field, but your UI would be a little prettier.

Also, in Firefox anyway, the URL shown in my status bar when I mouse over your "ugly" link shows the unencoded version, so it would probably look fine there as well.