# remove amp; from value in mvc3 razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html-encode

I need to remove amp; from value in mvc3 razor

> @Microsoft.Web.Helpers.Video.Flash("/Content/flash/tc.swf", width:
>   "790", height: "150", options: new { FlashVars =
>   "root=/Content/flash/modeli&butt_info=/Content/flash/modeli/btn_1.png&butt_info_over=/Content/flash/modeli/btn_1_1.png&butt_build=/Content/flash/modeli/btn_2.png&butt_build_over=/Content/flash/modeli/btn_2_1.png&tit=/Content/flash/modeli/main_title.png&txt=Fiat
>   Gama&macchine=/Content/flash/modeli/00.png,/Content/flash/modeli/01.png&stitolo=/Content/flash/modeli/car_title.jpg,/Content/flash/modeli/car_title.jpg&codici_rif=201,196&CarNames=201,196"})

in browser `&` is encoded like `&amp;` and then swf file cant recognize the value

I tried @html.raw and other solution that I find on web but it dosent work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC URL decode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609927/asp-net-mvc-url-decode)

Answer (score 1):

Try `Server.HtmlDecode("...")` or `HttpUtility.UrlDecode("...")`.