# How to make href link?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, hyperlink, html-helper

I use AD Gallery. but my images is in folder that name equal product create date. 
Every model's images is in **@Model.Date.Value.ToShortDateString()** named folder. In this code img src="" works, but href="" does not work:

```
<div class="ad-thumbs">
  <ul class="ad-thumb-list">
     <li>
       <a href="http://localhost:20234/Products/Images + @Model.Date.Value.ToShortDateString() + @Model.ImagePath1">
          <img src="@Url.Content( Path.Combine( "~/Products/Images/", @Model.Date.Value.ToShortDateString(), @Model.ImagePath1 ) )" width="42" height="42" alt=""/>
        </a>
     </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I also tried

```
<a href="Path.Combine("http://localhost:20234/Products/Images", @Model.Date.Value.ToShortDateString(), @Model.ImagePath1)">
...
</a>
```

and

```
<a href="~/Products/Images" + @Model.Date.Value.ToShortDateString() + @Model.ImagePath1">
...
</a>
```

In AD Gallery down small images seems, but large images does not opens.
How can I write href link to open large images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `Url.Action`

```
<a href="@Url.Action(Path.Combine("http://localhost:20234/Products/Images", @Model.Date.Value.ToShortDateString(), @Model.ImagePath1))">
...
</a>
```

Also read [Razor code between double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249770/razor-code-between-double-quotes)

**Update 1:**

```
@Url.Action(string.Format("http://localhost:20234/Products/Images/{0}/{1}", @Model.Date.Value.ToShortDateString(), @Model.ImagePath1))
```

From MSDN:

```
public static string Combine(
    string path1,
    string path2
)
```

You provided 3 parameters.

or

```
@Url.Action(Path.Combine("http://localhost:20234/Products/Images", Path.Combine(@Model.Date.Value.ToShortDateString(), @Model.ImagePath1)))
```

to use `Path.Combine`

**UPDATE 2:**

```
<a href="<%=Url.Action(string.Format("~/Products/Images/{0}/{1}" , @Model.Date.Value.ToShortDateString() , @Model.ImagePath1))%>">
...
</a>
```

**UPDATE 3:**

```
<a href="<%=Url.Content(string.Format("~/Products/Images/{0}/{1}" , @Model.Date.Value.ToShortDateString() , @Model.ImagePath1))%>">
...
</a>
```

Comment: path name is so :
http%3a%5Clocalhost%3a20234%5CProducts%5CImages%5C31.08.2012%5Cimagename.png

Comment: Read here about decoding url: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609927/asp-net-mvc-url-decode

Comment: Please help.
in any case, there is "Images" string at the begin of path. for examle:
/Images/~http%3a%5Clocalhost%3a20234%5CProducts%5CImages%5C31.08.2012%5Cimagename.png . That is why images not open

Comment: @Mores see updated code for an alternative (see after `or` phrase)

Comment: runtime it seems..why? before link "Images" appears:
<a href="/Images/http%3a/localhost%3a20234/Products/Images%5C31.08.2012%5Ccategory.png" class="ad-thumb0">...</a>

Comment: Did you try my last written code ? `@Url.Action(Path.Combine("http://localhost:20234/Products/Images", Path.Combine(@Model.Date.Value.ToShortDateString(), @Model.ImagePath1)))`

Comment: I tried your all variants, but in every link's begin there is "Images"
 like this:  href="/Images/~/http.....

Comment: Means that you have something wrong in route or ... somewhere else. All codes above works for me...

Comment: replace url.action with url.content in one of my code provided then

Comment: Yesss, 
href="@Url.Content( string.Format( "http://localhost:20234/Products/Images/{0}/{1}", @Model.Date.Value.ToShortDateString(), @Model.ImagePath1 ) )"
now it workss, thank you))))

Answer (score 1):

Why not use Jquery ?

```
<a href="#" id="addQuick" date="@Model.Date.Value.ToShortDateString()" path="@Model.ImagePath1" class="callmyJquerymethod">name</a>
```

jquery:

```
 $(document).on("click", ".callmyJquerymethod", function () {
   var requrl = '@Url.Action("redirectoAction", "YourController", null, Request.Url.Scheme, null)';
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: requrl,
            data: { date: $(this).attr("date"),path:$(this).attr("path") },
            success: function (data) {
               // q.e.d.
            }
        });
```

In controller :

```
 public ActionResult redirectoAction(string date, string path)
        {
           string link=string.Format("localhost:20234/Products/Images/{0}/{1},date,path); 
           return Redirect(link);
        }
```

This should do it ! Use debugger and let me know if it reaches the controller.

Comment: Do not use `.live()` since its been depricated.

Comment: and that's a reason for a -1 ?

Comment: As a side-note: In jQeury 1.4.2 `live` has been replaced by `delegate` and since 1.7 `live` is depracated and `on` is the preferred method.

Comment: Yes, that is a reason for -1. Because .delegate is also depracated. -1 is gone

Comment: Its not about the down vote. Its about the quality of my code.

Comment: I dont know jquery well. how should I wrote action?

Comment: Action= name of the method from your controller 
Controller= your controller; data: the parameters of your method in MVC

Comment: in this case i want to create link to open image. for example: 
"http://localhost:20234/Products/Images/12.08.12/imagepath1"
In your sample, i wrote :
var requrl = '@Url.Action("http://localhost:20234/Products/Images/" + @Model.Date.Value.ToShortDateString() + "/" + @Model.ImagePath1 )';
But not opens yet..

Comment: it doesnt reach to the controller action.. also i changed $('#addQuick'), because there is class="ad-thumb0" at runtime.

Comment: use '<div class="ad-thumbs callmyJquerymethod">'

Comment: Syntax is wrong, I'll correct it. It's not just replacing .live with .on - http://api.jquery.com/live/